# Full text search for entity with user

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, jhipster

I have a simple web application with two entities:

- User
- State (with field: User ownerUser)

User can create and read own States. I created full text search (elasticsearch) for States but my search returns me all States, not only created by logged user. I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
public Page<StatusDTO> search(String query, Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("Request to search for a page of Statuses for query {}", query);
    String login = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin();
    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(queryStringQuery(query))
        .withFilter(boolQuery().filter(termQuery("ownerUser : login", login)))
        .build();

    Page<Status> result = statusSearchRepository.search(searchQuery.getQuery(), pageable);
    return result.map(statusMapper::toDto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
.withFilter(boolQuery().filter(termQuery("ownerUser.login", login)))
```